# Let $(X, T)$ be a topological space and let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $X$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, T)$ be a topological space and let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $X$.

Ext(cl(A)) subset of EXT(EXT(CL(A))

Could you please help me find a counterexample? I spent a lot of time on it.

Comment: what is ext in topology?

Comment: @OfekGillon the complement of the closure.

Comment: What examples have you tried?  Almost any example at all is a counterexample...

Answer (score 1):

Taking $A$ and $B$ closed (so $A\cup B$ closed as well) you actually ask for a counterexample of $A^c\cup B^c\subseteq(A\cup B)^c$ or equivalently: $$A\cup B\subseteq A\cap B$$I guess you can find one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Take $X = [0,2]$ in the usual topology. Let $A = [0,1], B = [1,2]$.

$\operatorname{Ext}(A) = (1,2], \operatorname{Ext}(B) = [0,1), \operatorname{Ext}(A \cup B) = \operatorname{Ext}([0,2]) = \emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

What does "Ext(A)" mean?  Is it the "exterior" of A, the collection of all points that are not in A?  If so this is not really a "topology" question since it has nothing to do with "open sets".  It is simply a set question.  You ask for a "counterexample" so you want to give an example for which this is false.

Take A= {1, 2, 3} and B= {3, 4, 5} as subsets of {1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} so that Ext(A)= {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} and Ext(B)= {1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9].

Ext(A)U Ext(B)= {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

AUB= {1, 2 3, 4, 5} so Ext(AU B}= {6, 7, 8, 9}

Here Ext(AUB) is a subset of Ext(A)U Ext(B) but the other way is NOT true.

Comment: "Exterior" is a standard term in topology for the complement of the closure of a set.  Your example works for the discrete topology though.